# SimpleDateFormat issue - type mismatch

Tags: java, datetime, nullpointerexception, simpledateformat, type-mismatch

I have simple method for changing a string value into a date, but I keep receiving errors. I have imported import java.sql.Date.

```
String lastDate = lastDate();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
try {   
    Date datum = formatter.parse(lastDate);  // type mismatch here
    System.out.println(datum);
    System.out.print(formatter.format(datum));
} catch (ParseException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get the error:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date`

If I put (Date) infront of formatter.parse(lastDate); I get zero errors until I run the program. The method lastDate successfully returns the last date from the SQL database, but then I get the errors bellow.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at meritve.prvi.main(prvi.java:108)
```

Comment: String lastDate = lastDate();, You have date value in lastDate..?

Comment: And even check lastDate is of java.util or java.sql

Comment: No, @Hema, that cannot be the case with the error messages reported (it would have given “cannot convert from Date to String” instead).

Comment: see if he is getting lastDate as null, in tht case also this happens right

Comment: Gregor, are you saying `lastDate` comes from your SQL database as a string? You can probably get some date or date-time type out of the database so you won’t need to do the parsing in Java. For example `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime`, `LocalDateTime`, `LocalDate` or `java.sql.Date`, depending on the type in the database, the way you are retrieving it and the version of your JPA or JDBC driver.

Comment: @ Olve V.V. yes the lastDate is basically a string which comes from SQL. I agree that it is probably better to use one of the types you mentinoned. Will try that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have imported `java.sql.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`'s [parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) method returns `java.util.Date`, so you can't convert `formatter.parse(lastDate)` to `java.sql.Date` type, so `import java.util.Date` or else use the complete class name as shown below:

> I still get the bellow error: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Add a `null` check as shown below so that the date parsing logic will be executed only when `lastDate` is not null.

```
  if(lastDate != null) {
         java.util.Date datum = formatter.parse(lastDate);
         System.out.println(datum);
         System.out.print(formatter.format(datum));
    }
```

Comment: I have replaced the code as following:
String lastDate = lastDate();

  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
  try { 
   java.util.Date datum = formatter.parse(lastDate);
   System.out.println(datum);
   System.out.print(formatter.format(datum));
  }

Unfortunately I still get the bellow error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 
  at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)

 at meritve.prvi.main(prvi.java:109)

Comment: I guess this happens because `lastDate()` returns `null` in some cases.

Comment: @javaguy thank you very much. It really was a problem with lastDate(). It works now!